# Need help MSSQL query to bring table with two columns into one showing unique value of field 1 and corresponding values in field 2 (in that order)?

Tags: sql-server

[Picture of current state and desired state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyBhN.jpg)

Need help MSSQL query to bring table with two columns into one showing unique value of field 1 and corresponding values in field 2 (in that order)?  See picture attached in link above

Comment: Please share relevant code snippet

Comment: You might represent the data in a spreadsheet like that in a single column, but not in a relational database. A relational database has tables which contain rows and columns. Each column contains values of the same type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your request sounds quite strange, but if you want to do it, one way is to use rollup + grouping_id like this:

```
select case when grouping_id(field2) = 1 then field1 else field2 end
from yourtable
group by field1, rollup(field2)
order by field1, grouping_id(field2) desc, field2
```

Usually you'd use this for subtotals, but using it with case you can add additional rows to the data.

This will return:

```
x
a
b
c
d
y
e
f
g
z
h
i
```

Edit: How to list table + column names:

```
select case when grouping_id(c.name) = 1 then t.name else c.name end
from sys.tables t join sys.columns c on t.object_id = c.object_id
group by t.name, rollup(c.name)
order by t.name,c.name
```

Comment: This works. Thank you so very much. Genius. I don't understand exactly what all the syntax means though(grouping_id, rollup) in particular.

Comment: @jazo Rollup is used to create subtotals, and grouping_id can be used to check if the row is the subtotal (=returns 0/1)

Comment: Do you know how to create a similar query that will list the table name, followed by all the column names in that table?  I have 5 tables in total.

Comment: @jazo Well that's the exact same query, just replace the field1 and field2 with the table and column names. Added that to the answer.